# Computing the second derivative with chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider the curve parameterized by
$$x=1/3 t^3+3t^2+2/3$$

$$y=t^3-t^2$$

Compute $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$ at $t-1$

I computed $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3t^2-2t}{t^2+6t}$

The solution says that $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}= \frac{d/dt * dy/dx}{dx/dt}$ I'm a little confused by this.

I understand that the variables are in terms of $t$ but why can't i just do the quotient rule on $dy/dx$ to get the second derivative? Also I  don't understand how they got $dx/dt$ in the denominator.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}\frac{dx}{dt} $ by the change rule. Now divide.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about it abstractly and formally may help.

If you have
$$
x=f(t),\quad y=g(t)
$$
then
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}=\frac{g'(t)}{f'(t)}\tag{1}
$$
Now, introduce the notation $z=\frac{dy}{dx}$, $h(t)=\frac{g'(t)}{f'(t)}$ and write (1) as
$$
z=h(t). 
$$

Your goal is to fine $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ which is exactly $\frac{dz}{dx}$. Now, by
$$
x=f(t),\quad z(t)=h(t)
$$
you play the same game again:
$$
\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dz/dt}{dx/dt}
$$
But
$$
dz/dt=\frac{d}{dt}(z)=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dy}{dx})
$$
So
$$
\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dy}{dx})}{dx/dt}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac {d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac {d}{dx}(\frac {dy}{dx})=\frac {\frac {d}{dt}}{\frac {dx}{dt}} (\frac {dy}{dx})=\frac {\frac {d}{dt}(\frac {dy}{dx})}{\frac {dx}{dt}} $$

Note that your $\frac {dy}{dx}$ is a function of $t$ so we follow the chain rule to find its derivative with respect to $x$